# How does the use of the copy() algorithm from Exception C++ Chapter 1 Part 1 work?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, copy

Herb presents a way to loop through the vector:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); i++) {
 cout << *i << endl;
}
```

He replaces this code with:

```
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```

I am struggling to understand how, or why, this works.  I looked up the copy function and the documentation says that it is equivalent to:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
                       OutputIterator result)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    *result = *first;
    ++result; ++first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

So I developed the question, "What happens when we * OutputIterator?"

```
reference operator*() const;

Dereference iterator
Returns *this.
```

And that is where I got confused.  I do not see a definition of what OutputIterator is pointing to.  Additionally, I do not see how the line  `*result = *first;` could possibly translate to invoking `cout << *i;`

Comment: Have a look at ostream_iterator. Its operator=() does the magic.

Comment: BTW: this is a nice example on how to work with algorithms, but in C++11 `for (const auto& obj: myObjVector) { std::cout << obj << std::endl; }` is preferred for its simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only looked up what an `OutputIterator` does. `OutputIterator` is just a set of requirements that a bunch of types in the standard library meet. One of those types is the `std::ostream_iterator`, so you need to look at how this behaves in the context of `std::copy`.

So in the copy algorithm, we're doing `*result = *first`. Firstly, the `operator*` for `std::ostream_iterator` does nothing - it just returns the iterator itself. The magic happens when we assign to this iterator. If you look up [`std::ostream_iterator::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator%3D), you'll see that assigning to this iterator will insert (using `<<`) into the stream it was constructed with. So the assignment in your case will stream into `std::cout`.

After this, both `result` and `first` are incremented. Incrementing `result` (the `std::ostream_iterator`) has no effect, and incrementing `first` will move to the next element in the vector. Then in the next iteration, this next element is inserted into `std::cout` again, and so on.

As you can see, `std::ostream_iterator` doesn't really behave in the way that you would expect a typical iterator to behave (moving through a sequence of elements where performing indirection on them gives you the current element). However, it *does* meet the requirements of an `OutputIterator` and so can be used as one.

---

Here's the implementation of `std::ostream_iterator::operator=` from libstdc++:

```
/// Writes @a value to underlying ostream using operator<<.  If
/// constructed with delimiter string, writes delimiter to ostream.
ostream_iterator&
operator=(const _Tp& __value)
{
  __glibcxx_requires_cond(_M_stream != 0,
                          _M_message(__gnu_debug::__msg_output_ostream)
                          ._M_iterator(*this));
  *_M_stream << __value;
  if (_M_string) *_M_stream << _M_string;
  return *this;
}
```

Ignoring the assertion on the first line, we can see that it then inserts `__value` into its internal `_M_stream` stream. Then, if there is a delimiter set, `_M_string`, it also gets inserted into `_M_stream`. Then it returns.